# move existing Windows XP to a new harddrive

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, installation, ssd

I've bought a SSD for my laptop and made a fresh install of Windows 7.
On my old HDD I've got a Windows XP system, which I would like to move to the SSD.

I've tried it this way:

- put the HDD to an USB case
- moved the Windows XP partition to a partition on my ssd usind DriveImage XML
- used EasyBCD 2.0 to create a new entry in the boot menue

The problem:
Windows XP is booting up, but before the login-screen comes up, it seems to freeze.
No bluescreens, no errors - just nothing happens.
I tried to start it in "protected mode", but the same results.

I'm not sure if DriveImage XML didn't worked well or if there's another reason.

Comment: Check if the drive in in AHCI or COMPATIBLE mode. Windows XP doesn't have SATA drivers, so AHCI mode will freeze the OS, although it is usually a BSOD. Second, use Linux :-) to make a perfect copy of your disk. Third, if you bought a smaller SSD than your original HDD, you might be in trouble. Partition-to-partition copy was always wonky to me, so I prefer disk-to-disk copy. I suggest you remove a lot of stuff from your HDD, so it would entirely fit on your SSD, defragment it, and after that do a disk-to-disk copy.  In Linux, use the `dd` command to copy the disk. You can use a Gparted Live CD

Comment: @karatedog, your comment should be an answer. My first thought was dd...

Answer (score 0):

I have used Seagate DiscWizard to great success

### [seagate.com/support/downloads/discwizard](http://seagate.com/support/downloads/discwizard)

Comment: Only works with Seagate and Maxtor drives however. @svnpenn Sorry, I forgot they absorbed Maxtor

Answer (score 0):

Since he's not posting it himself...

> Check if the drive in in AHCI or COMPATIBLE mode. Windows XP doesn't have SATA drivers, so AHCI mode will freeze the OS, although it is usually a BSOD. Second, use Linux :-) to make a perfect copy of your disk. Third, if you bought a smaller SSD than your original HDD, you might be in trouble. Partition-to-partition copy was always wonky to me, so I prefer disk-to-disk copy. I suggest you remove a lot of stuff from your HDD, so it would entirely fit on your SSD, defragment it, and after that do a disk-to-disk copy. In Linux, use the dd command to copy the disk. You can use a Gparted Live CD